# Why does exporting under Unity 5 for iOS result in a file 10x larger than the original?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I imported my custom package into Unity 5 for ios, which was 74MB, then when exported jumped to 700+MB! what's happening here?

Comment: _"Insufficient data for meaningful answer"_  - Isaac Asimov.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the build logs to see what is getting put into your build.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html

After you run the build you should be able to get some stats from the build, it produces a lot of information but typically the build size info starts with "Used Assets, sorted by uncompressed size:" from there you can see what is taking up size in your build.

If you are building for WebGL the file size will be bigger because unity has to put the entire engine in the build, since the engine wont be previously installed via the webplayer every build has to have all of the code in it.